# How eclipse generates .classpath file?

Tags: java, eclipse, build-process

When we create a Java project in Eclipse IDE, we get a `.classPath`  and a `.project` file. Can you guys please give me some idea how eclipse generates both files?

Comment: It creates two text files and writes Xml structures into them.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Can you please suggest where is the configuration in eclipse to create those files.

Comment: generally if you modify your build path the .classpath file changes...changing any project related things like project nature, configuring builder changes those files...whenever you create an eclipse project it internally creates those files for you

Comment: If you want to programmatically modify the classpath entries http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_classpath.htm

Comment: Thanks Saurav for your comment. I want to know the internal process how eclipse create both files. Is there is any configuration file to create it?

Comment: There is no one configuration file, the contents are partly from values specified on the New Project wizard and partly from various Preference settings.

Comment: The files are internal configuration files that eclipse uses for memoizing information about your project. You should not need to worry about these files. They are created automatically, and eclipse uses them internally. Why do you want to play with them? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The `.classpath` file holds the same information that the Eclipse GUI presents as the *build path* information. The `.project` file holds all the other project-specific information that Eclipse has, except for UI related information, which it places in files in the `.settings` sub directory.

Comment: Well, `.settings` is not reserved to UI related stuff. Easier to say the other way round: `.projects` just stores the natures and builders of a project ("what kind of project is it").